# SQL query to find the most number of vendors per a given location

Tags: mysql, sql, count, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

Can you help me to find the proper MySQL query to get the most numbers of vendors per a given location and list them all by name and name of their shop:

1 - The query must find out which location has the highest number of vendors then list them by name with the name of the shop they work in.

I have the following tables:

```
CITIES 
(
 ID "unique",
 NAME
)


SHOPS
(
 ID "unique",
 NAME,
 CITY_ID ( foreign key of CITIES TABLE ID)
)

VENDORS
(
 ID "unique",
 NAME,
 SHOP_ID ( foreign key of SHOPS TABLE ID)
)
```

Example with dummy data

```
CITIES : NY, SF

SHOPS: Boom - NY, Flash - NY, Sofast - SF

Vendors:

Mark : Boom,
John : Boom,
Carlos : Sofast,
Alex : Sofast,
David : Flash,
James: Flash
```

The NY has the highest number of vendors so it should list

```
Mark : Boom, John : Boom, David : Flash, James: Flash
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if this works -

```
Select vendors.name, shops.name 
from 
cities inner join shops on cities.id= shops.city_id
inner join vendors on shops.id = vendors.shop_id
where cities.id = (select id from (select cities.id, count(1) from 
cities inner join shops on cities.id= shops.city_id 
inner join vendors on shops.id = vendors.shop_id 
group by cities.id order by 2 desc) limit 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you could approach this with window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select x.*, rank() over(order by cnt) rn
    from (
        select v.*, count(*) over(partition by c.id) cnt
        from cities c
        inner join shops   s on s.city_id = c.id
        inner join vendors v on v.shop_id = s.id
    ) t
) t
where rn = 1
```

The most inner query joins the three tables, and counts how many vendors each city has. The next level ranks records by descending count. Finally, the last level filters on top-ranked rows.